# reading a .DAT file with HEX delimiter in talend

Tags: file, delimiter, talend, read-data

I have a requirement where a .DAT file with data delimited with a HEX code needs to be read in talend.

Below is the sample data -

[image]

I have tried tfileinputdelimited, tfileinputpositional, tfileinputraw but nothing worked as expected. **The delimiter is a HEX 00x7 or BEL - [click here](https://bytetool.web.app/en/ascii/code/0x07/)**

How can I read this kind of file in talend ?

Your help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Link to example please. Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly. Also, what actually does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the utf-8 representation of the character in the field separator: \u0007
[image]